# Why websocket sendMessage is required

Tags: websocket

This is the code taken from the book  **"The Definitive Guide to HTML5 websocket"**

```
div id="output"></div>
<script>
function setup() {
output = document.getElementById("output");
ws = new WebSocket("ws://localhost:7777");

ws.onopen = function(e) {
    log("Connected");
    sendMessage("Hello Websocket!");
}

ws.onclose = function(e){
    log("Disconnected: " + e.reason);
}

ws.onerror = function(e){
    log("Error ");
}

ws.onmessage = function(e) {
    log("Message received: " + e.data);
    ws.close();
}

}

function sendMessage(msg){
ws.send(msg);
    log("Message Sent");
}

function log(s){
var p = document.createElement("p");
p.style.wordWrap = "break-word";
```

Could anybody please let me know for what reason this below event is required ??.

```
 ws.send(msg);
```

I understand that the below will call the **onMessage** method on server side as shown below

```
public void onMessage(String data) {

}
```

But the actual purpose of **onMessage** on server side is to send data from backend to the javascript which will inturn call `onmessage`  of client side javascript .

could anybody please help me understand this .

Answer (score 1):

In the above code the `ws.onopen, ws.onclose, ws.onmessage` are all *events* associated with WebSocket object.

Whereas `ws.send()` is a *method* associated with WebSocket object. There is a huge difference between them.

The following event ensures that the  Web Socket is connected to the server i.e you've opened your connection

```
ws.onopen = function(e) {
    //Once you've opened your connection
    //you can begin transmitting data to the server 
    //using the following method
    ws.send("You\'re message");
}
```

So the main purpose of `ws.send()` method is to **transmit data from the client to the server** which is done by simply calling the WebSocket object's send() [in your case `ws.send(msg)`].

And also ***send data only takes place once a connection is established with the server*** by defining an `onopen` event handler.